# Gurobi - addConstr: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'bool' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, gurobi

I have the following piece of code in Python in order to add a new constraint:

```py
for o in range(num_origins):
    for d in range(num_destinations):
        for i in range(num_launchpads):
            for j in range(num_launchpads):
                model.addConstr(ground_time_min[o][d] >= ground_time_min[o][i] + (Y[o][d][i][j] - 1) * M)
```

Only `Y[o][d][i][j]` is a variable. `ground_time_min` is a parameter and M is a big number, also a parameter.

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'bool' and 'NoneType'
```

I know:

1. The types are neither bool or None. So, That is not the problem.
2. `ground_time_min` on the left-hand side is causing the problem.

I managed to fix the problem using either of these two approaches:

1. Moved the left-hand side to right:

```
model.addConstr(0 >= ground_time_min[o][i] - ground_time_min[o][d] + (Y[o][d][i][j] - 1) * M)
```

2. Used another syntax:

```
model.addConstr(ground_time_min[o][d], GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, ground_time_min[o][i] + (Y[o][d][i][j] - 1) * M)
```

The documentation says:

> Left-hand side for the new constraint. Can be a constant, a Var, a LinExpr, a QuadExpr, or a TempConstr.

So, I am not sure what is wrong with the constraint as formulated initially. Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried your code and did not get any error. Could you show your definitions of `ground_time_min` and `Y` (maybe for a minimal working example)?

Answer (score 0):

You must define Gurobi Variables for all of your objective function coefficients. At least `ground_time_min[o][d]` must be Gurobi variable.

You should first define variables on gurobi as mentioned in [Gurobi Help](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/variables.html), then use those variables with the second syntax you used above.

You may check out an implementation exmaple on C++ [Integer Programming Example](https://github.com/faydogan/Minimum-Spaning-Tree-Gurobi/blob/master/MSTP%20-%20Gavish%2C%20Graves.cpp)